# AWK, Compare of two files then compare the other field for the match one and do arithmetic

Tags: shell, unix, awk, compare

**File A**

```
Jimmy|03-OCT-18|BST100114261|20000
Dedi|03-OCT-18|BST100904288|10000
Jimmy|03-OCT-18|BST100114262|120000
```

**File B**

```
Anton|9800
Jimmy|90000
```

**Output**

```
Jimmy|20000|90000|1800000000|BST100114261
Jimmy|120000|90000|30000|BST100114262
```

Logic:

1. Find the same Jimmy
2. Compare amount between File A (column 4) and File B (column 2), if File A (column 4) less than File B (column 2) then multiple File A (column 4) and File B (column 2). If it is less, then deduct File A (column 4) and File B (column 2)

Note :

- 90000 > 20000 then 20000 * 90000 = 1800000000
- 90000 < 120000 then 120000 - 90000 = 30000

  3. Display output as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN   {FS=OFS="|"} 
       NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} 
       $1 in a {v=a[$1]; print $1,$4,v,(v>$4?$4*v:$4-v),$3}' b a

Jimmy|20000|90000|1800000000|BST100114261
Jimmy|120000|90000|30000|BST100114262
```

**Explanation**

> set the delimiters for parsing and printing the fields
>
> while scanning the first file (file b) where the linenumber and file line number are equal, fill up the lookup array with key value pairs.
>
> while scanning
>   the second file (now the third statement in the script), if the key in
>   in the array, print the fields in desired order and with the described
>   computation.
>
> To not to rewrite `a[$1]` multiple times assign it to
>   variable `v` (for value).

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl one-liner

```
> cat filea
Jimmy|03-OCT-18|BST100114261|20000
Dedi|03-OCT-18|BST100904288|10000
Jimmy|03-OCT-18|BST100114262|120000
> cat fileb
Anton|9800
Jimmy|90000
> perl -F"\|" -lane ' BEGIN { %kvp=map{chomp;split(/\|/)} qx(cat fileb)} { chomp;print "$F[0]|$F[3]|$kvp{$F[0]}|",$F[3]<$kvp{$F[0]}?$F[3]*$kvp{$F[0]}:$F[3]-$kvp{$F[0]},"|$F[2]" if $kvp{$F[0]} } ' filea
Jimmy|20000|90000|1800000000|BST100114261
Jimmy|120000|90000|30000|BST100114262
>
```